# pandas histogram in python. possible to make probability/density instead of count?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

Histogram in pandas plots the count of each bin, rather than the normalized fraction.  In R, this is an option in the histogram.  Is it possible in Pandas? If not, any recommendations for an easy workaround?

Answer (score 9):

For me this gives the desired results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5000))
df.hist(normed = True)
```

The 'density' option works in numpy's histogram function but not on pandas's hist function.

September 2023 update:
Pandas seems to have switched to using *density* instead of *normed*, approximately in 2020. New version of working code, as John points out, is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5000))
df.hist(density = True)
```

Comment: Normed gives me values of like 14 though.  Is it percentages?

Comment: Would i need df.np.hist then?

Comment: You mean the y-axis? What do you get when you use df.hist(normed = True) and df.hist(normed = False)? Both peak at zero but the former takes a maximum of about .4 and the other a maximum of about 1400.

Comment: oddly enough, when I do normed, I get a max of 8 on my Yaxis and when I do unnormed, I get a max of 3600.  Normed should put the Y axis between 0 and 1, unless it's not doing what I think it is...

Comment: Weird. That's not what I get. Do you get that 8 result on my sample code, your data frame, or both?

Comment: My data frame, I looked through other stack questions and noticed other people got this, too. No good explanations about what "normed" is doing.

Comment: `normed` has been replaced by `density`.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass density parameter to hist, like this

```
df.hist(..., density=True)
```

Here, density is passed as kwds to np.hist.

Reference: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: How can I make it recognize NUMPY hist when I have both pandas and Numpy loaded?

Comment: Here, density is passed as kwds to np.hist. So it is automatically recognized. (it is written on pandas documentation.)